# Progressive line width increase in corel draw

Tags: corel-draw

I would like to know if it is possible to draw a line in corel draw with variable width. I need to draw a line which is 1 px at the beginning and then grows progressively to 3 px at the end.

The line is a very difficult curve and I really can't figure out a way to do it.

I really hope this can be done. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 2):

With "Artistic Media". There are some verey simple steps:

[image: Artistic Media]

1) Draw your line

2) Press "i" or go to your "tool bar"

3) Choose the style you want

4) In the "property bar" choose the maximum width.

5) You can just change the fill or the outline as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

converting the line (and its current thickness) to an object could help,
though it would be better to have the line have various thicknesses at different points rather than start, middle and end.

Comment: welcome to gdSE! This is not really the type of answer we're looking for, would be better if added as a comment instead. Check this guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: well it IS an answer to the question, it just didn't seem to be the right one for the person asking, not so??
Corel has no variable width stroke like Illustrator yet, so THIS is my current solution

Comment: Check the other answer. It is older and it does answer the question. You suggest converting the line to an object, but doesn't go into describing how this would solve the issue of creating the line asked, hence my comment.